# Linear Algebra - injective and subjective linear function.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

I have this problem :

Let $B_{nxn}$ matrix there's a function $f:M^R_{nxn} \rightarrow M^R_{nxn}$ so $f(A)=BA$

- Is $f$ subjective? if so proof it. else find a condition so $f$ will be subjective.
- Is $f$ injective? if so proof it. else find a condition so $f$ will be injective.

**My answer**

- No, assume $B=0 \implies \forall X \in M^R_{nxn} \implies F(X)=0X=0$ then $\exists M \in M^R_{nxn} \forall X \in M^R_{nxn} \implies F(X) \neq M$ Therefore not subjective.

Condition so $f$ will be subjective (not sure about this) is that $B$=inverse matrix, in that case $\forall X \in M^R_{nxn} \implies \exists M \in M^R_{nxn}$ so $f(X)=M$ (is this a valid proof?).

- No, assume $B=0$ and $C \neq D \implies f(C)=0=f(D)$,

Condition is to choose B=inverese matrix (not sure about this) therefore $C \neq D \implies f(C)=BC \neq BD=f(D)$ (Is this a valid proof?)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim is correct. But you can improve your proof. Assume that $B$ has inverse. Then,

- for any matrix $X$ it is $f(B^{-1}X)=BB^{-1}X=X,$ which shows that $f$ is sujective, and
- $f(A_1)=f(A_2)\implies BA_1=BA_2 \implies B^{-1}BA_1= B^{-1}BA_1 \implies A_1=A_2$ which shows that $f$ is injective.